# how to override property with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

How to override a property with prototype in Javascript?

## code

```
function Test(){
    this.prop = false;
}

Test.prototype.prop = true;

var T = new Test();
console.log(T.prop);
```

this returns `false` but should return `true` ??

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: You can't.  That's not what prototypes are for.  You're either asking the wrong question or looking to do something that makes no sense.  In virtually every system the most specific option takes precedence and you're looking to do the opposite.

Comment: @clarkk how can you do _what_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the value of the t property access the property directly from an instance of the object or specify it in the constructor.

**Direct Access**

```
var T = new Test();
t.prop = false;
console.log(T.prop);
```

**Constructor**

```
function Test(prop){
    this.prop = prop;
}

var T = new Test(false);
```

Comment: I need to change the property before the object is created

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is executed **after** the prototype copy. You can't override a property setted by a constructor by using the prototype.

But if you really want to do this, you can do this :

```
function Test(){
    if (this.prop === undefined) {
        this.prop = false;
    }
}
```